# Hadoop reduce function to output (key,valuelist)

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

The input data is like:

```
1 5 
2 8
1 3
2 7
4 9
```

The objective is to let the first number of each row be key, and the second number of each row be value. After shuffling I want the output (key,value_list)

But I don't know how to output a value list.

The output I expect is that:

```
1,[5,3] 
2,[7,8]
4,[9]
```

After mapping I got:

```
1 5
1 3
2 7
2 8
4 9
```

```
public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text> {
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        String token1  = tokenizer.nextToken();
        String token2  = tokenizer.nextToken();
        context.write(new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(token1)), new Text(token2));
    }
}

public static class Reduce extends Reducer<IntWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text> {
    String iterableToString(Iterable<Text> values) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[");

        for (Text val: values) {
            sb.append(val.get()).append(",");
        }
        sb.setLength(sb.length() - 2);
        sb.append("]");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

     //  context.write(key, new Text(iterableToString(values)));
    }
}
```

But there has an error message:

```
compile:
    [javac] /home/zih-yan/hadoop_tutorial/build.xml:12: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to /home/zih-yan/hadoop_tutorial/bin
    [javac] /home/zih-yan/hadoop_tutorial/src/f.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         sb.append(val.get()).append(",");
    [javac]                      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method get()
    [javac]   location: variable val of type Text
    [javac] Note: /home/zih-yan/hadoop_tutorial/src/f.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] 1 error
```

Comment: Could you share more details? Like sample input data, code snippets of your mapper/reducer class? By the way, if you need only `<key, list[values]>`, the mapper phase is just enough. But still, share more details so that we could help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,and I still have some question.I wanna get list[value], and only go through the map phase without shuffling seem can't get list[value]

Comment: What are you using to compile or edit your code? You should be see compilation errors in your IDE first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> output value list.

Then your reducer must output Text type, not `ArrayList`. You can only have Hadoop serializable types as your inputs and outputs.

That being said, problem can be extracted and individually *unit tested*.

```
String iterableToString(Iterable<Text> values) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[");
    
    for (Text val : values) {
        sb.append(val.get()).append(",");
    }
    sb.setLength(sb.length() - 2);
    sb.append("]");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Then once tests pass, you can use it

```
public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
  throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    context.write(key, new Text(iterableToString(values)));
}
```

Regarding your compilation error, make sure you are using the correct import for the Text class

Comment: Sorry to bother you.I have edited the code,but I still get the same error message.I wanna make sure that I haven't placed the code snippet in the wrong place. Thanks!

Comment: Like I said, make sure you import the correct `Text` class. - `import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;`

Comment: Yes.I import the correct Text class. But get the same error message. So,I change the iterable type to IntWritable to make the compilation pass. Thanks!